# Rspec doesn't see my model Class. uninitialized constant error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, model, rspec

I'm writing tests on Rspec for my models in Ruby on Rails application.
And I receive this error while starting 'rspec spec'

```
command:
/spec/models/client_spec.rb:4:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Client (NameError)
```

I use Rails 4.0.0 and Ruby 2.0.0

Here is my client_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'


describe Client do

  it 'is invalid without first_name', :focus => true do
     client = Client.new
     client.should_not be_valid
  end
end
```

And Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0.rc1'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0.rc1'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: 
gem 'turbolinks'

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.0.1'

group :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end
```

And at last client.rb (ROR Model and Class):

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :cars
  has_many :orders
  has_one :client_status
  has_one :discount_plan, through: :client_status

  validates :email, format: { with: /^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})\z/, :message => "Only emails allowed", :multiline => true }
  validates :email, presence: true, if: "phone.nil?"
  #validates :phone, presence: true, if: "email.nil?"
  validates :last_name, :first_name, presence: true
  validates :last_name, :first_name, length: {
      minimum: 2,
      maximum: 500,
      wrong_length: "Invalid length",
      too_long: "%{count} characters is the maximum allowed",
      too_short: "must have at least %{count} characters"
     }
end
```

If it'd be useful my spec_helper.rb file:

```
# This file was generated by the `rspec --init` command. Conventionally, all
# specs live under a `spec` directory, which RSpec adds to the `$LOAD_PATH`.
# Require this file using `require "spec_helper"` to ensure that it is only
# loaded once.
#
# See http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Configuration
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.treat_symbols_as_metadata_keys_with_true_values = true
  config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true
  config.filter_run :focus

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = 'random'

  #config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

   config.before(:each) do
     DatabaseCleaner.start
   end

   config.after(:each) do
     DatabaseCleaner.clean
   end

  end
```

Comment: What worked for me was removing the line `--require spec_helper` from `.rspec`. As it already contained `--require rails_helper`, which was being loaded after `spec_helper`.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Your `spec_helper` file is missing some important commands.  Specifically, it's not including config/environment and initializing `rspec-rails`.

You can add the following lines to the start of your `spec/spec_helper.rb` file

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
```

or you can just run

```
rails generate rspec:install
```

and overwrite your `spec_helper` with one generated for use with `rspec-rails`.

Comment: Newer versions of RSpec move some stuff out of the `spec/spec_helper.rb` file, so now you also get a `spec/rails_helper.rb` file. If you run `rails generate rspec:install`, [this is what it produces](http://pastie.org/9280896) (rspec-rails 3.0.1, rails 4.1.1). Turns out the `rails_helper.rb` file contains some similar code to yours and should be required when you want to load Rails in your specs.

Comment: Dennis is on the right track. I believe that configuration for tests that are going to be testing Rails capabilities should be moved from `spec_helper.rb` into `rails_helper.rb`. Also, be sure to read the comments in `rails_helper.rb` that mention how `rspec-rails` can `infer_spec_type_from_file_location`, which might make you relocate your spec tests into different `spec/*/` subdirs.

Comment: if you want to include `spec/rails_helper.rb` automatically you can do that in your `.rspec` by adding `--require rails_helper`

Comment: But doesn't adding `--require rails_helper` to `.rspec` defeat the point of separating the two helpers. I think then you'll always be loading rails_helper (and therefore Rails), even for specs that don't need Rails.

Comment: This helped a lot. I actually needed to update my `.travis.yml` to `bin/rspec`

Answer (score 185):

In rails 4.x and later (rspec-rails 3.1.0 and later) **add this to the top of each of your spec files**:

```
require "rails_helper"  # this
```

not

```
require "spec_helper"   # not this
```

Comment: This should be it's own question somewhere for Googling purposes; I have been struggling with what I thought was broken Capybara, or broken launchy, or broken (fill in the gem), and it was all due to this one line change.

Comment: require "rails_helper" work on rails 3.2.22 (rspec-rails 3.2.1)

Comment: This was super confusing. I'm building a new Rails 6 app and running my first spec. It was definitely loading the rails_helper.rb file, but I now see it was trying to load it after attempting to run the spec. Added `require "rails_helper"` to the top of my spec and I was good to go.

Answer (score 24):

You might also like to add `--require rails_helper` in your `.rspec` file so that it looks like this.

```
--color
--require spec_helper
--require rails_helper
```

You won't need to require rails_helper in all your specs, after this.

Comment: This is great if you need to load the Rails environment for every test, but if not this will eventually cause your test suite to be slower than it needs to be, as some have mentioned in the comments on another answer above.

Answer (score 10):

If other answers under this question don't work, try:

- Check if there is any typo in the file name or class name (they should match)

Other wise,

- Check your `config/environment/test.rb` file,
  see if there is `config.eager_load = false`, set it to `true`.

You should check in the written order since you don't want to solve the issue with the typo laying there.

Comment: Setting `config.eager_load` to `true` fixed the problem for me. Thanks!

Comment: Note that if you're requiring `spec_helper`, that there is this comment in `test.rb`:

`# If you are using a tool that preloads Rails for running tests, you may have to set it to true.`

Answer (score 8):

I'm using **Rails 5.0.0.1.**
Here's how I resolved this concern.

On your Gemfile, please add -> **gem 'rspec-rails', ">= 2.0.0.beta"**

Like so,

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', ">= 2.0.0.beta"
end
```

**Reason:** if the rspec-rails is not added and when you execute the rspec command, it will generate this error -> *"cannot load such file -- rails_helper"*

Now, execute this command on the terminal.

> bundle install

Once bundle command went good, execute the rails generate. Like so,

> rails generate rspec:install

**Reason:** this command will create a new .rspec(hit overwrite when prompted), spec/rails_helper.rb and spec/spec_helper.rb

Now, at this point, rspec should pretty much run properly.
However, if you encounter an error where in the model is not found e.g. *cannot load such file -- idea*, try adding this on top of your spec/spec_helper.rb

```
require 'rubygems'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
```

**Reason:** seems that spec_helper is not loading the Rails environment. We're requiring it.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 6):

None of the answers above quite hit the nail on the head for me, or weren't quite explicit enough with where lines of code needed to be placed. I'm using rails 6.0.2 and rspec-rails 4.1.0 and found two options that solved the issue.

1. Add the line `require 'rails_helper'` to the top of each spec file that you need to run.
2. Add the line `require 'rails_helper'` to the top of the `spec/spec_helper.rb` file to make the rails helper file available in all tests.

Answer (score 2):

Things have moved a bit since this thread has been created, I have experienced the `uninitialized constant ClassName (NameError)` error too using Ruby 2.1, Rails 4.2, rspec-rails 3.3.

I have solved my problems reading the rspec-rails gem documentation :

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails#model-specs

where it confirms what Swards says about requiring "rails_helper" not "spec_helper" anymore.

Also my model specification looks more like the one from the gem docs

```
RSpec.describe Url, :type => :model do
    it 'is invalid without first_name', :focus => true do
        client = Client.new
        client.should_not be_valid
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Factories folder define in your app

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user_params , :class => 'User' do
    username 'Alagesan'
    password '$1234@..'

  end
end
```

Your Controller RSpec file:

```
it 'valid params' do
  post :register, params: {:user => user_params } 
end
```