# Error when trying to run rspec: `require': cannot load such file -- rails_helper (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, command-line, rspec

I am trying to run rspec for Ruby on Rails.  I am running Rails 4.1.1.  I have installed the gem, have established a spec folder with some tests.  I have created a directory through `$ rails g rspec:install`

I tried to create a testing database through `$ rake db:test:prepare` but it throws this error message:

```
WARNING: db:test:prepare is deprecated. The Rails test helper now maintains your test 
schema automatically, see the release notes for details.
```

So I ended up looking at [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23351783/when-i-ran-bundle-exec-rake-testprepare-it-errored-out-but-bundle-exec-rake), and of the two options, the one that worked was:

```
rake db:schema:load RAILS_ENV=test
```

So, **now I need to run rspec**.

When I run `$ rspec spec` from the command line I get this error:

```
/Users/myname/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/
kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- rails_helper (LoadError)
```

How do I resolve this so that I can start running tests?

Comment: What's the output of `gem list --local rspec`? rspec-rails made an incompatible change a few versions back that's probably biting you because you're not using `bundle exec` or binstubs. Older versions use, generate, and require spec_helper only; newer versions use, generate, and require a spec_helper and a rails_helper. If you mix versions (which is likely what happened here), things will break.

Comment: It is:
    $ gem list --local rspec
    *** LOCAL GEMS ***
    rspec-core (2.13.1)
    rspec-expectations (2.13.0)
    rspec-mocks (2.13.1)
    rspec-rails (2.13.1)
Can you tell what the problem is from this list?  Any recommendations on next steps?

Comment: Make sure you're in the right directory when you run the specs.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

There is some problem with rspec V3. But in your case you are using V2.

change

```
require 'rails_helper'
```

to

```
require 'spec_helper'
```

Other description find here https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/problem-with-rspec

**For V3 :**

If someone using rspec V3 then similar error occurs when generator not run. So before trying anything run generator.

```
rails generate rspec:install
```

If you are getting a huge list of warning on your console. Then you need to remove `--warnings` from `.rspec` file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27934369/2968762 ???

Comment: Didn't get you.

Answer (score 68):

I actually just had this error on rails 4 with rspec 3, but in my case I forgot to run the generator:

```
rails generate rspec:install
```

Also I had to remove `warnings` from `.rspec`, as [stated by one of rpsec developers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24176446/rspec-capybara-loading-in-progress-circular-require-considered-harmful)

Comment: Surprisingly, this is what worked for me. I figured this wouldn't apply since I've already run the generator. This Q/A also helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17507416/rspec-doesnt-see-my-model-class-uninitialized-constant-error

Answer (score 14):

For me, the problem was due to a different "rspec-support" version loaded and activated. I solved by prepending a "bundle exec":

```
bundle exec rspec
```

Answer (score 6):

Always remember to run the
`rspec` or the `bundle exec rspec` from the root of your project.
Something like:

```
bundle exec rspec spec/features/file_test_spec.rb
```

Comment: this worked for me, rails 5

Answer (score 5):

For newer versions (3.5), if you need to run the generator, `rails generate rspec:install` doesn't work for me. I used:

```
rspec --init
```

Creates `.rspec` and `spec/spec_helper.rb`.

EDIT:
Just in case, I found out that I installed rspec gem for ruby, not the one for Rails, so rspec:install wasn't available. Should use https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes you need to run rspec command from Project's parent directory

Answer (score 4):

Please install the following gem:

`gem install 'rspec-rails'`

And then run:
`rails generate rspec:install`

This will generate the spec folder and **rails_helper.rb** and **spec_helper.rb**. Your error should be taken care once this is done.

Answer (score 3):

None of these suggestions worked for me on Rails 4.2.0 with rspec-rails 3.2.3.

Instead, I placed the following two lines at the top of my spec file:

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'spec_helper'
```

Now I can execute `rspec spec/features/my_spec.rb`.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error but there was no reference to `rails_helper` anywhere and we weren't even using rails.

However, I eventually found that my `~/.rspec` was requiring `rails_helper` (presumably from creating rails app in the past) which was causing the issue ...

```
$ cat ~/.rspec
--color
--format documentation
--require spec_helper
--require rails_helper
```

The fix is as simple as removing that line. Hope this helps someone else grappling with the same issue!

Comment: getting `.../2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1455:in `require': cannot load such file -- rails_helper (LoadError)` in Rails 5

Answer (score 2):

One possibility that worked for me is to make sure you're requiring `spec_helper`. RubyMine can default require `rspec` and this can sometimes lead to this error.

Answer (score 2):

You may also have your file named incorrectly. Make sure it ends in `_spec.rb`. I had misspelled my file to end in `_soec.rb` and was scratching my head for a while...

Answer (score 1):

I got the error you described when running a controller test. However, when I ran a model test, I got the true error. it ended up saying that the error was occuring because my database wasn't migrated. I fixed the error by running this command...

`rake db:test:prepare`

Comment: This is a great answer too. If you've ran your test suite without problems before and this error comes up, try this instead of modifying your testing configuration.
For rails > 4.0 use:
`rails db:test:prepare` instead of `rake`. Both will work but using the `rails ` keyword is the preferred way now.

Answer (score 0):

For someone. If you got that error when you trynna test a specific file. you might can like this

```
$ bundle exec rspec ./spec/features/user_login_spec.rb
$ bundle exec rspec ./spec/models/user_login_spec.rb
```