# Failure/Error: require 'rspec/rails' TypeError: wrong argument type Class (expected Module) Rspec V3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I understand that, this error is common but somehow I am not able to figure out the problem, seems like its path related.
I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25800122/error-when-trying-to-run-rspec-require-cannot-load-such-file-rails-helper) question also but no luck so far.

**Gemfile**

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.7'
  gem 'factory_bot_rails', '~> 4.0'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 3.1'    
end
```

**spec/factories/user.rb**

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    name "Andy"
  end
end
```

**spec/models/user_spec.rb**

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe User, type: :model do

it "should be invalid without phone number" do
    user = build(:user)
    user.phone = nil
    expect(user).not_to be_valid
  end
end
```

**spec/support/factory_bot.rb**

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods
end
```

**.rspec**

```
--require spec_helper
--color
```

**rails_helper.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'support/factory_bot'
...
...
```

I am running **bundle exec rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb**

Things I tried:

1. Added `require 'support/factory_bot'` in `rails_helper.rb` below `require 'rspec/rails'` line.
2. `rails generate rspec:install` (executed successfully)
3. rspec --init (executed successfully)
4. rake db:test:prepare (executed successfully)
5. Changed `require 'rails_helper'` to `require 'spec_helper'` in **user_spec.rb** but got error *NameError: uninitialized constant User* after run.

Here is the full trace:

```
An error occurred while loading ./spec/models/user_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: require 'rspec/rails'
TypeError:
  wrong argument type Class (expected Module)
# /Users/Imi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:181:in `include'
# /Users/Imi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:181:in `block in add_template_helper'
# /Users/Imi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:181:in `module_eval'
# /Users/Imi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:181:in `add_template_helper'
# /Users/Imi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:110:in `block in helper'
# /Users/Imi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:109:in `each'
# /Users/Imi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:109:in `helper'
# /Users/Imi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_controller/railties/helpers.rb:17:in `inherited'
# /Users/Imi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionview-5.0.6/lib/action_view/test_case.rb:11:in `<class:TestCase>'
# /Users/Imi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionview-5.0.6/lib/action_view/test_case.rb:10:in `<module:ActionView>'
# /Users/Imi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionview-5.0.6/lib/action_view/test_case.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
# /Users/Imi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
# /Users/Imi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
# /Users/Imi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
# /Users/Imi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
# /Users/Imi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
# /Users/Imi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
# /Users/Imi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
# /Users/Imi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
# /Users/Imi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
# /Users/Imi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
# /Users/Imi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
# /Users/Imi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
# /Users/Imi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
# /Users/Imi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
# /Users/Imi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
# /Users/Imi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
# ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:1:in `require'
# ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
No examples found.


Finished in 0.00789 seconds (files took 2.75 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures, 1 error occurred outside of examples
```

Comment: Please show the contents of your rails_helper file.

Comment: Also, the full stack trace would be helpful.

Comment: @moveson Added rails_helper.rb

Comment: What line does the error relate to? Can you show the stack trace?

Comment: Added the trace

Comment: @Imran Facing same problem here. Anything worked for you?

Comment: @Aparichith I degraded the active-admin gem version and it worked.

Comment: @Imran In my case I created an helper module as `class` instead of `module`.

Comment: Ohh yeah, I did that also. Sorry, I forgot to mention.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working.

Everything was at the place except for one thing.
**Replaced `module` with `class`.** I had a `lib` and a `helper` module which was causing the error. Just replaced `module` with `class` now it running like butter.

Comment: The only thing that could help us developers is to show which file failed to be loaded. In my case, I removed all the files from the project and started adding them one by one. Eventually, I've found the guilty files.